# Ubuntu upgrade to 20.04, cannot uninstall prior version of gnumeric

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, crash, mate, gnumeric

I upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 a few days ago using Software Updater.  After the upgrade, Gnumeric will not open my old gnumeric files. If I start Gnumeric then open a Gnumeric file, the hard drive lights a bit then it crashes.  There are errors on startup if I start it from terminal.

`(gnumeric:50306): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:13:09.939: Object class GnmFontButton doesn't implement property 'level' from interface 'GtkFontChooser'`

`(gnumeric:50306): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:13:09.939: Object class GnmFontButton doesn't implement property 'language' from interface 'GtkFontChooser'`

`(gnumeric:50306): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:13:09.939: Object class GnmFontButton doesn't implement property 'font-features' from interface 'GtkFontChooser'`

Synaptic reports Gnumeric version 1.12.46 as "installed", and "latest" versions. There are no alternative versions to "force version".  When Gnumeric is started, "Help > About" reports version 1.12.34 is running.  I have reinstalled 1.12.46 to no avail.  The Synaptics function called "complete removal" has been used, afterwards, Gnumeric 1.12.34 will still start from an icon on the Mate toolbar.  I have logged out of Mate and into Ubuntu (Unity?), and have the same problem.

It is possible that some years ago I used the force version function in Synaptic to run an older version of Gnumeric, but my memory is not clear, it could have been another program.

I believe the existence and persistence of a prior version of Gnumeric (somewhere in the file system) is why I can't open gnumeric files.

If anyone knows how, I would like help with removing the old version of Gnumeric.  Once it is deleted, I am hopeful the 1.12.46 version can be reinstalled and then I'll be able to open my gnumeric files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible that some years ago I used the force version function in Synaptic to run an older version of Gnumeric, but my memory is not clear, it could have been another program.

Only you can know. Indeed it is possible that a manually installed appliction is on the system. In the system `$PATH` where executables are searched, "local" paths have precedence. Thus, for example, if a manually installed executable is found in `/usr/local/bin`, it will take precedence over one installed using the package manager in `/usr/bin`. However, also an application installed using Snap will have priority. In your case, that is unlikely because a snap version typically will be more recent, not older, than an APT version.

IF you know the name of the executable (you can find it in the `.desktop` launcher of the application), then you can determine which executable is called with the command `which name_of_executable`. If it is not in `/usr/bin`, then you are using a version installed a different way, either a manually installed application or one installed using SNAP. The outcome of that command will indicate which executable is used, and the path of that executable will suggest how it was installed.

Comment: Thank you vanadium!  Using file manager I could see there was a symbolic link named gnumeric in /usr/local/bin which pointed to gnumeric-1.12.34 located in the same directory.  I renamed it to gnumeric.delete.  That allowed the Synaptic installed version to run, and I can open the needed files!  I upvoted your answer but it won't show due to my new account. Thanks will have to do! :-)

Comment: You probably will be able to "accept" the answer (click the checkmark next to the answer), which will also increase your score. I will upvote your question to help.